# How to read files with one key but multiple values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am just beginning working with Python and am a little confused. I understand the basic idea of a dictionary as (key, value). I am writing a program and want to read in a file, story it in a dictionary and then complete different functions by referrencing the values. I am not sure if I should use a dictionary or lists. The basic layout of the file is:
Name followed by 12 different years for example :
A 12 12 01 11 0 0 2 3 4 9 12 9

I am not sure what the best way to read in this information would be. I was thinking that a dictionary may be helpful if I had Name followed by Years, but I am not sure if I can map 12 years to one key name. I am really confused on how to do this. I can read in the file line by line, but not within the dictionary.

```
def readInFile():
    fileDict ={"Name ": "Years"}
    with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
        _ = next(f)
        for line in f:
                if line[1] in fileDict:
                    fileDict[line[0]].append(line[1])
                else:
                    fileDict[line[0]] = [line[1]]
```

My thinking with this code was to append each year to the value.
Please let me know if you have any recommendations.

Thank you!

Comment: key = name, value = array of years

Comment: Do you mean like this? `{'A': ['12', '12', '01', '11', '0', '0', '2', '3', '4', '9', '12', '9']}`

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you can split lines with `name, *years = line.split()` then do `fileDict[name] = years`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map 12 years to one key name. You seem to think that you need to choose between a dictionary and a list ("I am not sure if I should use a dictionary or lists.") But those are not alternatives. Your 12 years can usefully be represented as a list. Your names can be dictionary keys. So you need (as PM 2Ring suggests) a dictionary where the *key* is a name and the *value* is a list of years.

```
def readInFile():
    fileDict = {}
    with open(r"names.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            name, years = line.split(" ",1)
            fileDict[name] = years.split()
```

There are two calls to the string method `split()`. The first splits the name from the years at the first space. (You can get the name using `line[0]`, but only if the name is one character long, and that is unlikely to be useful with real data.) The second call to `split()` picks the years apart and puts them in a list.

The result from the one-line sample file will be the same as running this:

```
fileDict = {'A': ['12', '12', '01', '11', '0', '0', '2', '3', '4', '9', '12', '9']}
```

As you can see, these years are strings not integers: you may want to convert them.

Rather than doing:

```
_ = next(f)
```

to throw away your record count, consider doing

```
for line in f:
    if line.strip().isdigit():
        continue
```

instead. If you are using `file`'s built-in iteration (`for line in f`) then it's generally best not to call `next()` on `f` yourself.

It's also not clear to me why your code is doing this:

```
fileDict ={"Name ": "Years"}
```

This is a description of what you plan to put in the dictionary, but that is not how dictionaries work. They are not database tables with named columns. If you use a dictionary with key:*name* and value:*list of years*, that structure is *implicit*. The best you can do is describe it in a comment or a type annotation. Performing the assignment will result in this:

```
fileDict = {
           'A': ['12', '12', '01', '11', '0', '0', '2', '3', '4', '9', '12', '9'],
           'Name ': 'Years'
           }
```

which mixes up description and data, and is probably not what you want, because your subsequent code is likely to expect a 12-list of years in the dictionary value, and if so it will choke on the string `"Years"`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give this a try. You have clarified a lot of my misinterpretations. The reason I have _=next(f) is because the first line of my file lists the numbers of total lines in the file.

Comment: I've revised the bit about `next(f)` to take account your revised description of the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in one line :)

```
print({line[0]:line[1:].split() for line in open('file.txt','r') if line[0]!='\n'})
```

output:

```
{'A': ['12', '12', '01', '11', '0', '0', '2', '3', '4', '9', '12', '9']}
```

Above dict comprehension is same as:

```
dict_1={}
for line in open('legend.txt', 'r'):
    if line[0]!='\n':
        dict_1[line[0]]=line[1:].split()

print(dict_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Values in a dict can be anything, including a new dict, but in this case a list sounds good. Maybe something like this.

```
from io import StringIO # just to make it run without an actual file

the_file_content = 'A 12 12 01 11\nB 13 13 02'
fake_file = StringIO(the_file_content)

# this stays for your
#with open('names.txt', 'rt') as f:
#    lines = f.readlines()

lines = fake_file.readlines() # this goes away for you

lines = [l.strip().split(' ') for l in lines]

fileDict = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in lines}

# if you want the values to be actual numbers rather than strings
for k, v in fileDict.items():
    fileDict[k] = [int(i) for i in v]
```

In python there are constructs where most simple as well as complex things can be done in one go, rather than looping with index-like constructs.